# How to insert a empty textbox message in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I want to insert a message which says Type here for example in a textbox in MVC3.

How do I do it?

Can it be done in the Model class on the field declaration?

Please suggest any way of doing?

Comment: Is that static text which you want to show always unless the user removes it explicitly from the textbox ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the HTML5 **placeholder**. Works in chrome and firefox. U can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to make it work in IE and other older browsers.

[How to set up modernizr for placeholder](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name,new { placeholder = "Fill in your name" })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBox("Place textbox name here", "Place default value here")
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model field declaration here, new { Value = "Place default value here" }
```

If you want to use input mask then you may take look  here [jquery input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)